# How to legally stop a neighbors dog from barking at the fence, without contact with the dog?

Tags: dogs, training, vocalizations

I've tried to research how to stop a dog from barking, but the articles always seem to be on how to stop your own dog from barking, or if you don't own the dog, the best bet seems to be going through the court system, but how would someone, on their own property, stop a neighbors dog from barking at the fence? (the neighbor is unwilling to stop it and it barks very loudly, even late into the night)

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] to see how this site works, it only takes a minute. What exactly are you willing to do? Would you install some hardware along your fence that interacts with the dog (by emitting a sound or similar things)? Would you go out and indirectly interact with the dog by squirting water on it? Or do you want to get your neighbor to stop the barking? You can [edit] your question any time to add more details.

Comment: FYI a similar question https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7984/how-can-i-stop-my-neighbors-dog-from-jumping-the-fence

Comment: How is the fence shaped? Can the dog look trough? Is it between your garden and the dog's one? Or beneath a path?

Comment: Can you "study" what exactly is the dog barking at? I doubt that it is at the fence itself.

Comment: Call local authorities anonymously for noise pollution, disturbances, etc. Or get a good water spray and squirt it at the dog when it barks too much. If it was a stray you could probably shoo it off with a low power pellet gun.

Comment: You can you try to frighten the dog with some water? I once got frustrated by a small barking dog, and the water made him stop for a while. but a more long term solution might be to talk with the owners.